# Emacs automatically adding BOM to XML file

Tags: emacs, unicode

This appears to be related to [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7347758/emacs-hexl-mode-utf8-bom-issue) but I have exactly the opposite use case. I do not wish to insert a BOM but `emacs` appears to be inserting one in XML mode (without even being in `hexl-mode`). I am using GNU Emacs 23.3.1.

I have the following XML file:

```
$ cat a.xml 
<?xml encoding="UTF-16"?><a/>
$ xxd a.xml 
0000000: 3c3f 786d 6c20 656e 636f 6469 6e67 3d22  <?xml encoding="
0000010: 5554 462d 3136 223f 3e3c 612f 3e0a       UTF-16"?><a/>.
```

The file does **not** contain a BOM as can be seen.
When I try to open it with `emacs a.xml` this is what I see:
[image]

When I then switch to `hexl-mode` it appears that a BOM has been inserted:
[image]

This happens even if I start Emacs with `emacs -Q`.

Comment: Does this happen if you start Emacs with `emacs -q`? If not, post your init file (`~/.emacs` or `~/.emacs.d/init.el`). If it does, what about `emacs -Q`?

Comment: @Gilles Chinese characters also appear with `-q` and `-Q` as well.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to load the file with find-file-literally.

Answer (score 0):

With this tag, emacs will save the xml file as utf-16 big endian with bom.

```
<?xml encoding="UTF-16"?>
```

Ascii tag (from IANA character sets):

```
<?xml encoding="US-ASCII">
```